# Extracting a single field in django-filter

Tags: jquery, python, django, jquery-select2, django-filter

I have an application that uses django-filter.
I want to be able to add an external library select2 (jquery) only one field - user.
How can I "separate" user field to be able to then work on it using select2 (jquery) in template?

```
class MyForm(InlineForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel


class FreeDaysFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    user = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(queryset=User.objects.all())
    date_from = django_filters.DateFilter(widget=DateInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker'}))
    date_to = django_filters.DateFilter(widget=DateInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker'}))

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        form = MyForm
        fields = ['user', 'country', 'date_from', 'date_to']
```

Comment: Are you using a django + Select2 package at all such as django-select2?

Comment: Only django + Select2 @KevinBrown